# Sticky footer at the bottom in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm building a project in Angular 2, and I need a sticky footer which always must be at the bottom of the page, not fixed. Example: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uwJjr

The structure of 'app' component is like this:

```
<header-main></header-main>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Probably, the problem is not connected with Angular itself, but with only CSS. However, I tried implementing it like this:

```
app {
   min-height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 271px;
}
```

The result is awful:
[image]

The interesting thing is that if I turn off a position of footer in inspector, and turn on again, the footer becomes OK:
[image]

**SOLUTION**:

```
app {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -271px;
  display: table;
}

header-main,
router-outlet,
footer{
  display: table-row;
}

header-main {
 height: 60px;
}

router-outlet {
  position: absolute;
}

footer {
  height: 271px;
}
```

Comment: Have any soluting for this ?. I am facing same issue

Comment: any response . I need ur help

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR POSTING THE SOLUTION <3 <3

Comment: The `min-height: 100%;` did the trick for me, I was using `height: 100%`

Answer (score 8):

This how I solve sticky footer (not fixed)

```
app.component.ts
.....
export class AppComponent {  
   clientHeight: number;

 constructor() {
    this.clientHeight = window.innerHeight; 
 }
 }

app.component.html

<div [ngStyle]="{'min-height': clientHeight + 'px', 'margin-bottom': '-200px'}"> 
          <!-- 'margin-bootom': '-FooterHeight' -->
    <app-navbar></app-navbar> 
          <!-- Your Navbar here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div style="height: 200px"></div> 
          <!-- 200px is FooterHeight  this will push 
          the footer so it will not overlap if you have very long content  -->
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer> 
<!-- Your footer here -->
```

Answer (score 4):

this is the first time I write here :D
I'm currently learning angular 7 and I had the same problem...
So I created my own solution (probably not the best but I think it can help some1).

HTML:

```
<div class="main-root">
    <header></header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.main-root {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The link you provided is actually a great example of how to accomplish what it sounds like you're asking for. I've tried to use the elements you mentioned with the necessary CSS below.

[Here's a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbgByJ).

```
<div class="app">
    <header>
        Header here
    </header>
    Content isn't long enough to push footer to the bottom.
</div>
<footer>
    This is the footer
</footer>
```

```
html, body {
    /* make sure the body does not have a margin */
    margin: 0;
    /* this forces the body tag to fill the height of the window */
    height: 100%;
}
.app {
    /* the .app div needs to be AT LEAST 100% of the height of the window */
    min-height: 100%;
    /* now that it is 100% the height, we 'pull' the footer up */
    /* margin-bottom must be the same height as the footer height below */
    margin-bottom: -271px; 
}
footer{
    /* .set the height of the footer */
    height: 271px;
    /* just setting a color so you can see the footer */
    background: orange; 
}

/* the following is not necessary, just showing how a header could be added */
header{
    height: 30px;
    background: teal;
}
```

Comment: 'footer' is inside 'app' tag: <app><footer></footer></app>

Comment: Sticky footers have always been rather tricky. They rely heavily on having just the right HTML layout for one element to at least fill the entire height of the page, and then pull the footer back up into the viewport (using a negative margin bottom). Without changing the HTML, the only other way I could think to make this work would be writing JavaScript that sets height of elements on page load and anytime you resized the window. I would personally favor using HTML/CSS over JavaScript for a sticky footer.

Answer (score 0):

See Example: [Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxoWXx)

Add CSS:

```
.page-wrap{position: relative;}
#add{position: absolute; bottom: 160px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

reply to "phen" answer. you can do It some more dynamic to support multi device (when footer height change):

```js
app.component.ts
.....
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {  
   clientHeight: number;
   footerHeight:umber;
   @ViewChild('footer') footerDiv: ElementRef;

 constructor() {
    this.clientHeight = window.innerHeight; 
 }
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.footerHeight=this.footerDiv.nativeElement.offsetHeight; 
 }
 }

app.component.html

<div [ngStyle]="{'min-height': clientHeight-footerHeight + 'px'}"> 
    <app-navbar></app-navbar> 
          <!-- Your Navbar here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer #footer></app-footer> 
<!-- Your footer here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the proposed solution for Angular8 and it didn't work. For some reason, think because of bootstrapping, the style is not applied for "app" tag. So, I assigned an ID to the "app id='main-app'" and changed the style to be applied by #ID. It worked.

```
#main-app {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 min-height: 100%;
}
```