# Sticky footer in Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, flexbox, material-design, angular-material2

I have been searching and searching for about 3 hours now because I didn't want to have to ask, but how can I keep a 'footer' variable at the bottom but not like fixed at the bottom, so if the content I have is very small it won't just sit halfway in the page but if I have lots of information it won't lock right at the bottom of the page and sit there over data while you scroll

I have tried several ways including this:
https://david-kerwick.github.io/2017/01/14/material-2-flex-layout-making-a-sticky-footer.html
and most questions related to this I've tested and failed with or don't seem to work at all.

Heres my current code:

```
<div class="content">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

and the `<app-content></app-content>` is within the navbar because the navbar controls a fullpage sidenav.

The whole app-navbar looks like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>

  <mat-sidenav mode="push" #sidenav>
    <div fxLayout="column">
      <mat-toolbar fxLayoutAlign="center center" color="primary">
        <button mat-icon-button routerLink="/home" (click)="sidenav.close()">
          <mat-icon>keyboard_backspace</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-toolbar>
      <button mat-button routerLink="/dashboard" (click)="sidenav.close()" >Information</button>
      <button mat-button routerLink="/second" (click)="sidenav.close()" >Web tools</button>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="fixed-navbar mat-elevation-z10">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.open()" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-xs>
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <div fxLayout="row">
      <button fxLayout="flex-shrink: 0;" mat-button class="title" style="font-size: 25px;">{{this.title}}</button>
      <button fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-xs mat-button routerLink="/dashboard" [matMenuTriggerFor]="infoMenu">Information</button>
      <button fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-xs mat-button routerLink="/second" [matMenuTriggerFor]="toolsMenu">Web tools</button>
    </div>
    <!-- fxFlex will fill the empty space and push the following items to the right -->
    <div fxFlex></div>
    <button mat-icon-button>
      <mat-icon>face</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <app-container></app-container>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

And the footer is just a super basic component that looks like this:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <div class="container">
    <span>this is a toolbar</span>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Only styling ive applied so far is this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa');
.title {
  font-family: "Comfortaa";
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Which is in the global style.css file.

Comment: Worth noting that even the official fixed header/footer with sidenav example has the same problem. It may just not be do-able atm and we might have to wait for more updates to material

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**An approach that uses Flexbox:**

When we utilize Flexbox we can get a **cleaner** solution. Also my solution will cover that the first component of your page should take 100% of the height. This is often needed to position elements appropriately or to work with backgrounds. The code matches the current version of Material 2 - at the time of writing this is 2.0.0-beta.12.

Markup:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="all-wrap" fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/']"> Foo</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/bar']"> Bar</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <div class="page-wrap">
    <header role="banner">
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button
          type="button"
          mat-icon-button
          (click)="sidenav.open()"
          title="Open sidenav">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        Your Toolbar
      </mat-toolbar>
    </header>
    <main class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Your sticky footer with a variable height.
    </footer>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Styles:

```
/*
 * Actual Sticky Footer Styles
 */
.all-wrap {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.page-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}


/*
 * Make the Component injected by Router Outlet full height:
 */
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  > *:not(router-outlet) {
    flex: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

You can find a more detailed description in a [Blogpost](https://blog.thecodecampus.de/material-2-sticky-footer-mat-sidenav/) that I wrote since I was unhappy with the solution I found here. There is also a [demo](https://cankattwinkel.github.io/material-2-sticky-footer-mat-sidenav/).

Comment: Just want to say that this solution is still brilliant and works with the latest version of Material (5) and the latest version of angular along side it (5)

Comment: I don't understand how this makes the footer sticky, I don't see any css applied to the footer? idk

Comment: @AlexanderMills excellent question, the footer is indeed not altered. Instead the containing `div.page-wrap` is made a flexbox column and then the `main.content` is set to `flex:1`. So he takes up all space.

Comment: You can actually play around with this on flexy boxes http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=column&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=stretch&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution in few lines:

**app.component.html:**

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlexFill>
    <app-header></app-header> // your header
    <div fxFlex>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> // your content
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer> // your footer
</div>
```

**styles.css:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Another alternative** if you prefer to fill the footer instead of your content:

**app.component.html:**

```
<div fxLayout="column" style="height: 100%;">
    <app-header></app-header> // your header
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> // your content
    <app-footer fxFlexOffset="auto"></app-footer> // your footer
</div>
```

**styles.css:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here:
[Sticky footer at the bottom in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355652/sticky-footer-at-the-bottom-in-angular-2)

**Solution**

```
app {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -271px;
  display: table;
}

header-main,
router-outlet,
footer{
  display: table-row;
}

header-main {
 height: 60px;
}

router-outlet {
  position: absolute;
}

footer {
  height: 271px;
}
```